# Add borderColor for map Highcharter R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How to add a border for map plot in Highcharter in R? 
In https://jkunst.com/highcharter/articles/highcharts-api.html showed `borderColor = '#EBBA95'`, but it change border inside map

What I need:
[image]

What I have with this function:

```
library(highcharter)
hcmap("countries/nz/nz-all", 
      borderColor = "darkred")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `borderColor` of the chart via `hc_chart()`:

```r
library(highcharter)
hcmap("countries/nz/nz-all") %>% 
  hc_chart(borderColor = "darkred", borderWidth = 10)
```

[image]